# How to give a label position in Java?

Tags: java, jlabel

I'm trying to give the label's a position but label1.setLocation(27, 20) doesn't work:

```
label = new JLabel( "Voer dag in" );
label1 = new JLabel( "Voer dag in" );
```

I want them under eachother

The whole code: http://pastebin.com/Gqtcqc9g

Thanks

Comment: You need to have a look at [layout managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) to do this kinda stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best practice is to use layout managers
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html 
Each container component usually has default layout manager.
If you REALLY need absolute layout, you can set it to null. Component.setLayoutManager(null)

In your case you need to set GrigLayout (simple one) or GridBagLayout(more flexible)

Answer (score 0):

try this out:

```
label = new JLabel( "Voer dag in" );

label.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 20);

//label.setBounds(x, y, width, height);

panel.add(label)
```

To move them easily you can use this aswell:

```
int xx = label.getBounds().getX();
int yy = label.getBounds().getY();
int ww = label.getBounds().getWidth();
int hh = label.getBounds().getHeight();

//to the right 10 units
xx+=10;
label.setBounds( xx, yy, ww, hh );

//that would be label.setBounds(xx+10,yy,ww,hh);
```

hope this helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

You use `JPanel` to show components, which have `FlowLayout` as default, because of you can't position your components with help of `setLocation()`.`FlowLayout` lyout components one by one in row.

For positioning component you need to use different [`LayoutManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html). For example you can try [`GridLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) or [`GridBagLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)